# Call chrome extension function and get response

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, google-chrome-app

I have an website 'http://localhost/sample'. I need to call a function in extension for echo a word and get response. How to implement such code and what are the permissions needed

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications), [Nativemessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) (You would need `nativeMessaging` permission instead), or any other communication method to exchange data between extension and your local server

The following code sends a simple http get request and output the response.

You may also want to use the [Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en) instead of Ajax, it depends on your need.

manifest.json

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "http://localhost/sample"
    ]
    ...
}
```

background.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responsetText);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/sample');
xhr.send();
```